# Using VBA to Call on AppleScript

Tags: excel, vba, applescript

I have the below apple script that works.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    open application file "Microsoft Excel_2.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
    tell application "Microsoft Excel_2"
        
        open "/Users/ben/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Desktop/Emod_Calc/Emod_Calc_2020.xlsm"
        
        run VB macro "SaveReportAsPDFIn2020"
        
    end tell
end tell
```

how do I call on this script in the VBA module?

None of the places I have looked explicitly explains this.

What is the command within vba to call and use this script?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/applescripttask or https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/applescripttask.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't understand the parameters or handler logic and so it wont let me thats why I am asking here.... so someone can explain it because neither of them make sense to me.

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but even if I did I'm sure I couldn't do as good a job at explaining it as Ron's page linked in my comment.  You can't skip the AppleScript and use `Workbooks.Open` to open the file with the macro?  Not sure why you need the script.

Comment: I need the Apple script to open a duplicate application of excel. This simulates opening another “instance” like in windows.